# ExoPlayer - How to get source code for the default layout?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm reading this tutorial on configuring the default exoplayer view's layout:

https://exoplayer.dev/ui-components.html

However it doesn't display the source code for the default player layout `exo_player_control_view.xml`

I've tried searching the entire project as well `CTRL + SHIFT + F` but that doesn't return anything

[image]

The bottom section is the layout im trying to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout you're looking for is here : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/res/layout

As pointed out by mcc:
Note, the above is if you are using the Exoplayer release, if you are using the Jetpack/Media3 version of exoplayer then the exo_player_control_view.xml corresponding to your library is https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/release/libraries/ui/src/main/res/layout/exo_player_control_view.xml

Comment: It's not possible to check it out in android studio?

Comment: if you want to change the default layout you only need to create a file with the same name and make your change in this layout

Comment: Note, the above is if you are using the Exoplayer release, if you are using the Jetpack/Media3 version of exoplayer then the exo_player_control_view.xml corresponding to your library is https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/release/libraries/ui/src/main/res/layout/exo_player_control_view.xml